# Custom ruby gem loads forever when sending first POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, rubygems, httprequest

I wrote a custom ruby gem that makes simple HTTP requests using the following code:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
request.body = body
response = Net::HTTP.new(myhost, myport)
response.ssl_version = :TLSv1  
response.use_ssl = true
response.verify_mode = ::OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
response.start {|http| @res = http.request(request) }
```

When I try to call it from my Rails app, it loads/does nothing for about 10 seconds before making the actual POST request. Calling it again after that is almost instant thought, so I assumed the dependencies are loaded in this time.

The gem requires:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'openssl'
```

so I simply declared 'json' and 'openssl' as runtime requirements in the gemspec. After running

> bundle install

they get installed but the 10 seconds loading time is still there.

I am calling a different method before the one above and that works perfectly fine so the gem is loaded properly.

Does anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: This sounds like a network issue, but it is impossible to tell without knowing your network setup. Maybe your company's DNS server shuts down after a period of inactivity and needs 10 seconds to start. Maybe your company's HTTP(S) proxy shuts down after a period of inactivity and needs 10 seconds to start. Maybe the HTTP server that is receiving the POST request shuts down after a period of inactivity and needs 10 seconds to start. Maybe the web application (or some component or dependency of it, like the database server or the connection to it or the JVM) that is processing the POST request …

Comment: … shuts down after a period of inactivity and needs 10 seconds to start. For example, if this is a Java web application, hosted on some cloud service with dynamic instance management, then the first request would require starting the VM, booting the OS inside the VM, starting the JVM, booting the container inside the JVM, start the web application, start the database server, load the database, connect to the database, and so on, before the request can be answered.